# TypeError:svg__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.node is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, typeerror

I need to draw an svg in canvas at specified location x, y but I going through a serious of errors. And I could not solve this....
App.js

```
const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
Utillities(ctx);
```

In app.js code for canvas is perect but drawing is giving error

Utillities.js

```
import stone from './assets/diamond.svg';
export const Utillities = (ctx) =>{
const x = "34.6";
const y = "45.4";
var img = new Image();

var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(stone.node);
var svg64 = btoa(xml);
var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
var image64 = b64Start + svg64;
img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}
img.src = image64;
}
```